# Do raid bosses have better IVs on average?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have recently defeated a raid boss (Exeggutor) and successfully caught it. When I appraised him, it was in the highest IV rank of my team with one 15 IV stat, so my question is:

Has anyone found anything that states that a raid boss will be a Pokémon with higher IVs or was I just lucky?

I have done some research, but at this point I didn't see my question answered.

Comment: Specifically asking for developer statements is off-topic for Arqade.

Comment: @Frank While the specific request for something from the dev may be off topic, I feel like the question as a whole is alright, as it can be answered with anecdotal experience, although it may be a bit early for that at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently if you successfully catch a raid boss, the level of the Pokemon is level 20. Like hatching a Pokémon from an egg.

The IVs distribution differentiate between 10 - 15 Points randomly per stat.

Reference:
Data from various catches on Silph Road

Comment: As a senior researcher of the silph road, I can confirm this is right.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, raids produce higher IV pokemons since their stat floors are much higher compared to regular mons. Here are several scenarios:

- Raids = 10/10/10
- Lucky Trade = 12/12/12
- Best friend trade (non-lucky) = 5/5/5
- Weather boost IV (non legendary, non raid) = 5/5/5
- Research Breakthrough = ?/?/?
- For reference: Max IV (100%) = 15/15/15

Weather boost adds 5 levels for all mons. Helpful for Legendaries so you start at level 25 instead of 20 for dust and candy costs. Weather boost does not affect legendary IVs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes correct:

I have competed in many raid battles, and they are all above 92% IV. However, I am not sure whether whether there is a definite lower bound, or it is generated at random like catching regular Pokemon.

My Raid Pokemon include:

- Bayleef 96
- Croconaw 94
- Snorlax 98
- Tyranitar 93
- Arcanine 95
- Magikarp 92

Well, if you are wondering "Wait, if Raids have only been out for a couple of days, how did you get to enter so many gyms?"

My answer is: "Well, I brought them with Pokecoins, as much of a waste as it looks..."

Comment: I've caught 5 raid pokémon so far and only 2 of them were 82%+. I think that I probably just got very unlucky...

Comment: Have you misread it? Or am I very lucky? And is it because I'm Level 40? Or maybe the teams? I only posted the answer because I read about personal experience

Comment: I think I was just quite unlucky, a friend of mine (Level 28) also got 5 out of 6 pokémon at 82%+ IV (I am Level 30)

Answer (score 1):

Niantic's blog post on [Raids](http://pokemongolive.com/en/post/raids) says

> If you successfully defeat the Raid Boss within the five-minute time limit, you’ll have the chance to catch an extra powerful Pokémon of your own!

Considering how a raid Pokémon appears as an egg before starting, the Pokémon's IVs are likely derived from the egg hatching mechanism.

Comment: I don't think the raid boss hatching from an egg really means much in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your luck; I have very good ones and also sucks ones:
Best 3:
Tyranitar 100
Snorlax 98
Tyranitar 96

Worst:
Tyranitar 70+
can't remember...transferred quite a lot.